# Android Wear - Xamarin no system images installed for this target - SDK manager not showing relevant SDKs (Visual Studio)

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I have been looking around to try and fix this common issue with the system images not being installed for the target. Nearly all questions have answers to go to the SDK manager and install the correct stuff... But for some reason I do not have all of the SDKs that are needed.

[image]

I have the latest version of Xamarin and I am trying to create a virtual device for the Android Wear Square. What can i do to fix this? I did see some answers to do with folder directories but as far as i could tell it was just for Eclipse.

[image]

Is anyone able to help me as to where to find the extra SDKs/ images?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that all the "Official Add-on Sites" are enabled in the SDK Manager:

[image]

And then perform a "Packages / Reload":

[image]

Comment: I don't have any add-on sites?

Comment: Then your install of Android SDK manager is messed up as you should alway have the "official" sites listed, whether they are enabled or not. Custom sites go under "user-defined". You can trying reinstall the manager or as a shortcut *try* adding them as "user-defined" sites till you can test a reinstall....

Comment: I have reinstalled Xamarin and it still hasn't got any of them there?

Comment: @Brendon Strange.... permissions issue on reading the settings for SDK manager?.... Try installing just the Android SDK Manager yourself, https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html (Scroll down to **"Get just the command line tools"**) This is the file that Xamarin is silently executing/installing...

Comment: I have done that now... still nothing if not worse as only the standard tools are installed...

Comment: @Brandon No need for that... Just install it and run it to verify that you are getting all the proper add-in site and thus all the APIs, images, etc... are available to you for download. If that works, personally I would just point VisualStudio/Xamarin to use that install (`In Visual Studio, from the Tools menu, select Options > Xamarin > Android Settings.` `In Xamarin Studio, Xamarin Studio menu, select Preferences > Projects > SDK Locations > Android.`)

Comment: @Brandon std tools?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120427/discussion-between-brendon-and-sushihangover).